# emberjs set deeply nested undefined key

Tags: ember.js

I have a model with a property response, containing a json with various keys and nesting levels

I can bind an input field to a one level missing key, but not more

for example if after loading the model

```
model.response = { key1: { c1: 12} }
```

naturally, I can do

```
{{ input value = model.reponse.key1.c1}}
```

and see 12 in the input field

but, I can do

```
{{ input value = model.reponse.key1.miss1}}
```

which will be recorded when I save the model, and found on page reload

but I cannot do

```
{{ input value = model.reponse.misskey1.miss2}}
```

with two levels of missingness.

Not only the value is not saved, but also a computed property with dependent key 
'reponse.misskey1.miss2' on the model is never triggered on input change

Do I need to set all missing keys or is there any other way to make it work ?

In this situation, shall I use unknwonProperty handler ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We used `setUnknownProperty` (or `unknownProperty`) in one of our projects. We didn't make it recursive, it just provides one level of unknown property. (That was enough for us.) So developers can generate crud screens quickly as such:

```
{{our-input-component "item.x" label=(t "intl.item.x")}}
{{our-input-component "item.y" label=(t "intl.item.y")}}
```

We tried this and it has been working without any problem for about eight months.

BUT, this is the two-way binding. You should avoid using two-way binding. This causes your app to violate the **Data Down Action Up** principle.

Ember input helper's common usage is the same with yours. (`value = model.reponse.misskey1.miss2`) You should make value assignment with one-way binding and you should handle the change/input events to make your property assignment in these event/action handlers. Or use other component families such as [ember-one-way-controls](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-one-way-controls).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the ready() call back of the model
and it works

```
 if (this.get('response.misskey1') === undefined){
         this.set('response.misskey1', {})
      }
```